# Refactoring tag dispatching structure

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, tags

I have following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <utility>

struct real_type {

    struct real_category{};
    typedef real_category num_category;    
}; 

struct imag_type: public real_type {

    struct imag_category{};
    typedef imag_category num_category;
};

template<class number_type>
struct number_traits {

    typedef typename number_type::num_category num_category;  
};

void print_num(double x, double y, typename real_type::num_category) {

    assert(y==0);
    std::cout<<"real num - x: "<<x<<std::endl;
}

void print_num(double x, double y, typename imag_type::num_category) {

    std::cout<<"imag num - x: "<<x<<", y: "<<y<<std::endl;
}

template<int Y=0, typename num_type = typename std::conditional<Y==0, real_type, imag_type>::type >
void print_num(double x) {

    typename number_traits<num_type>::num_category num_category;
    print_num(x, Y, num_category);
}

int main() {

    print_num(1);
    print_num<3>(2);

    return 0;
}
```

With output:

```
real num - x: 1
imag num - x: 2, y: 3
```

I'm not really happy with the behavior of this code. As can be seen, I'm constrained for imaginary values to integers. Also I must call the imaginary-variant of print_num with a trailing `<>`, which isn't elegant as well.

The reason for this construction was, that in order to deduce the correct category-tag I had to check the value of `Y`. But this check was only possible in the template parameter list.

So my question is: Is it possible, while keeping this tag-dispatching structure (i.e. keeping the functions `void print_num(..., typename real_type::num_category)` and `void print_num(..., typename imag_type::num_category)` as they are, to define the dispatching function like`void print_num(double x, double y=0)`. This would mean (?) to somehow deduce the correct num_category by checking if `y==0` or not.

I know I could just solve this by checking this with a `if(y==0)\*then call print_num with real_category tag*\else \*call with imag_category tag*\` in the `void print_num(double x, double y=0)` function. This would make the number_traits class obsolete (which I don't want). I.e. I would like to make this decision in the template parameter list. Is this possible? I think not (?)

**update:**

Based on the answers I rewrote the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <utility>

struct real_type {

    struct real_category{};
    typedef real_category num_category;
    struct real_number{ double x; };
    typedef real_number num;
    num num_x;
}; 

struct imag_type: public real_type {

    struct imag_category{};
    typedef imag_category num_category;
    struct imag_number{ double x; double y; };
    typedef imag_number num;
    num num_xy;
};

template<class number_type>
struct number_traits {

    typedef typename number_type::num_category num_category;  
};

void print_num(real_type r, typename real_type::num_category) {

    std::cout<<"real num - x: "<<r.num_x.x<<std::endl;
}

void print_num(imag_type i, typename imag_type::num_category) {

    std::cout<<"imag num - x: "<<i.num_xy.x<<", y: "<<i.num_xy.y<<std::endl;
}

template<typename num_type>
void print_num(num_type i) {

    typename number_traits<num_type>::num_category num_category;
    print_num(i, num_category);
}

int main() {

    real_type r_type;
    r_type.num_x.x = 1.1;
    imag_type i_type;
    i_type.num_xy.x = 2.1;
    i_type.num_xy.y = 3.2;

    print_num(r_type);
    print_num(i_type);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
real num - x: 1.1
imag num - x: 2.1, y: 3.2
```

It's working now. Not entirely sure, if this code is now consistent with the tag-dispatch concept

Comment: `print_num(double x, double y=0) { if (y == 0) print_num(x, y, real_type::num_category{}); else print_num(x, y, imag_type::num_category{});` . Though I fail to see the point. With a signature like `print_num(double x, double y=0)`, you clearly expect to check `y` at run-time. What's the point of a tag dispatch then, which is a compile-time metaprogramming technique? You say that tag dispatch is non-negotiable - but why? What purpose do you believe it serves here?

Comment: Thanks, that was my point: To get an answer whether tag dispatching is useful in this particular example: No! because checking whether y==0 is done at run-time

Comment: Tag dispatch is for choosing an algorithm at compile time, based on some compile-time characteristic of the input (e.g. `std::distance` would be implemented differently for random-access iterators vs forward iterators). I don't see how it can be usefully applied to this case.

Comment: Made an edit. Working now. As you seem to be an expert in metaprogramming, you can maybe look over this.

Comment: I still don't see the point. Just having two (regular, non-template) overloads of `print_num`, one taking `real_type` parameter and the other `imag_type`, would do the trick. It's also not clear why `imag_type` is derived from `real_type` - as written, it carries three `double` members rather than two.

Comment: Concernig your first point: I did that because I want to hide the two `tagged` `printnums` behind the generic one. The idea is to deduce the template parameter-type from the one parameter type in the function's parameter list. A kind of static polymorphism. Concernig your second point: Yes, that's true, I could change that

Comment: Just do `void print_num(real_type r) { /* something for real number */ }` and `void print_num(imag_type i) { /* something for complex number */ }` . You wouldn't need no tag dispatch, and would have nothing to hide.

Comment: So you could forget this example as well: http://www.generic-programming.org/languages/cpp/techniques.php#tag_dispatching . Kick the generic method, then kick the tags and use the special iterators as parameters in the specialized functions instead of the template iterator arguments

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better of checking the imaginary part at runtime rather than compile time. Here's an example that uses `std::complex`

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>

template<class T>
auto print(std::complex<T> const& c)
{
    std::stringstream sstr;
    if (std::abs(c.imag()) < std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()) {
        sstr << c.real();    
    } else {
        sstr << c;    
    }
    return sstr.str();
}

int main()
{
    auto const c1 = std::complex{1.0};
    auto const c2 = std::complex{2.0, 3.0};

    std::cout << print(c1) << "\n"; // prints: 1
    std::cout << print(c2) << "\n"; // prints: (2, 3)
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uRojzdokvFeMrky1)

Comment: Yep, I of course know that there are 1000 solutions that solve this particular example much better. But this isn't the point of my question. I'm somehow having this problem with my 2 last questions here under c++. I'm not that much interested in getting any solution to my example, but a solution constrained to a particular concept as Igor Tandetnik correctly pointed out. I'm posting these kind of questions to get a feedback whether I understood a concept correctly and if a particular concept can be applied to a particular example or not.